# using set clause in spring cypher query

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

please provide me some example to use set clause in cypher query using java.

i just want to update property of relationship object but it always fail.
if i am running query like

```
    ExecutionResult executionResult = engine.execute("start n=node:Person(name=\"suresh\"),n2=node:Email(subject=\"Hi\") match (n)-[r]-(n2) return r ");
    System.out.println(executionResult);
```

i am getting proper response like below

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| r                                                                                                                           |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| :DynamicRelationshipType[Have][69] {accessed->true,__type__->"org.test.spring.neo.domain.EmailRelationShip",relation->"To"} |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 rows, 260 ms
```

but when i am trying to run query like

```
start n=node:Person(name=\"suresh\"),n2=node:Email(subject=\"Hi\") match (n)-[r]-(n2) CREATE SET r.accessed=true return r
```

it always fail
stack Trace

```
expected return clause
    "start n=node:Person(name="suresh"),n2=node:Email(subject="Hi") match (n)-[r]-(n2) CREATE SET r.accessed=true return r "
                                                                                       ^
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.parser.v1_6.CypherParserImpl.parse(CypherParserImpl.scala:65)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.CypherParser.parse(CypherParser.scala:42)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine$$anonfun$prepare$1.apply(ExecutionEngine.scala:60)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine$$anonfun$prepare$1.apply(ExecutionEngine.scala:60)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.LRUCache.getOrElseUpdate(LRUCache.scala:31)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.prepare(ExecutionEngine.scala:60)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:54)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:51)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.java:63)
        at org.test.spring.neo.controller.MediatorController.main(MediatorController.java:34)
```

i tried to execute like below also but this one is also failing

```
ExecutionResult executionResult = engine.execute("start n=node:Person(name=\"suresh\"),n2=node:Email(subject=\"Hi\") match (n)-[r]-(n2) SET r.accessed=false return r ");
```

i am referring http://docs.neo4j.org/refcard/1.9/ to create a read and write query

i am using sdn version 1.8.

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says: "expected return clause"

Neo4j 1.8 is more restricted than e.g. 2.0

e.g. something like this works:

```
start n=node:Person(name="abc"), n2=node:Email(subject="Hi") 
match (n)-[r]-(n2) 
set r.accessed=true
return count(*)
```

You should also always use parameters:

```
start n=node:Person(name={person}), n2=node:Email(subject={subject}) 
match (n)-[r]-(n2) 
set r.accessed=true
return count(*)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Michael.
this solution work perfectly when i am using it in neo4j console if i am not using return clause also.
but this is not working when i am trying to execute the query from java.

Comment: I am trying to execute this query like
 @Query(value = "start n=node:Person(name={0}),n2=node:Email(subject={1}) match (n)-[r]-(n2) set r.accessed=true")
 void setRead(String person,String Subject);
from Spring application and i am getting error while executing this.

Comment: You didn't add the return statement !!

Comment: added..
but still getting the same
`expected return clause
"start n=node:Person(name="suresh"),n2=node:Email(subject="Hi") match (n)-[r]-(n2) set r.accessed=true return count(*)"`